# Find Max number from List of String numbers using Java Streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I am trying to get max number among List of Strings.

My code is:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("00657");
list.add("00632");
list.add("00656");
list.add("01125");

Integer maxNum = list.stream()
                   .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
                   .max();
```

Above code is giving an error. Error is: ***Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: java.util.stream.Stream.mapToInt.max.*** 
I should get `1125` as a result. I tried different ways but none of them is working.

Comment: *"Above code is giving an error"* What error? Compile error or runtime error? What does the error say?

Comment: `.mapToInt(Integer::intValue)` is incorrect on a `Stream<String>`. You probably want `.mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)`. And the result is an `OptionalInt`, not an `int`/`Integer`

Comment: ernest_k  is it possible to get max number into integer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to parse the `String`s as `Integer`s which can be done using `parseInt`:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("00657");
list.add("00632");
list.add("00656");
list.add("01125");

int maxNum = list.stream()
        .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
        .max()
        .orElse(-1);
```

Because there are no guarantees your stream is not going to be empty, this is why the `orElse` is needed.

Answer (score 3):

`mapToint` does not map any object (such as `String`) to an integer. It is used to map `Integer` type streams to `int` stream.

You need to first map the `String` numbers to `Integer` using `map` with `parseInt` and then map the `Integer` to `int`.

Use the following piece of code:

```
  Integer maxNum = list.stream()
                        .map(Integer::parseInt)
                        .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
                       .max()
                       .getAsInt();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: 1) `parseInt()` returns an `int`, which causes `map()` to auto-box it, then `intValue()` is a manual unbox of that. --- 2) Code throws `NoSuchElementException` if list is empty. --- Combined, I declare this answer "not useful", since it is not good code.

Comment: Thank you for an explanation. Your answer is also working.

Answer (score 1):

@Abdusoli mapToInt can map only int type of data so you have to parse it into int first and final result is OptionalInt so it should be convert into Int.
You can try both the way

**First approach**

```
Integer maxNum = list.stream()
                .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
                .max()
                .getAsInt();
        System.out.println(maxNum);
```

**Second approach**

```
Integer maxNum = list.stream()
                .map(Integer::parseInt)
                .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
                .max().getAsInt();
        System.out.println(maxNum);
```

Answer (score 0):

**intValue** is not a static method,you should use **Integer::parseInt** instead. Also, **max()** return **OptionalInt** not **Integer**, you can use 
**max().getAsInt();** or **max().orElse();**

Such as

```
Integer maxNum = list.stream().mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).max().getAsInt();
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please click the *edit* button below your answer, then click the circled `?` in the upper-right corner and then the "Advanced help" link, to see a page that will teach you how to better format the answer, so it becomes *readable*.

Answer (score 0):

```
   Integer maxNum = list.stream()
            .map(Integer::valueOf).mapToInt(v-> v)
            .max().orElseThrow(NoSuchElementException::new);
```

You can try this one instead of intValue change to valueOf

Comment: Note: Starting from Java 10, `orElseThrow(NoSuchElementException::new)` can directly be replaced with `orElseThrow()` which behaves identical to `getAsInt()`